# Javascript write file without overwrite

Tags: javascript, firefox, filestream, xpcom, imacros

I am using XPCOM to read/write file(s) on my hard drive (since Java is no longer supported on FF16,17,18,+ I have to use this). I use it in my FireFox extension(s) (I use iMacros). On this document [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Firefox_addons_developer_guide/Using_XPCOM%E2%80%94Implementing_advanced_processes)  I found this example.

```
var string = '\u5909\u63db\u30c6\u30b9\u30c8';
file.initWithPath('C:\\temp\\temp.txt');
file.create(file.NORMAL_FILE_TYPE, 0666);
var charset = 'EUC-JP';
var fileStream = Components
.classes['@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1']
.createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream);
fileStream.init(file, 2, 0x200, false);
var converterStream = Components
.classes['@mozilla.org/intl/converter-output-stream;1']
.createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIConverterOutputStream);
converterStream.init(fileStream, charset, string.length,
Components.interfaces.nsIConverterInputStream.DEFAULT_REPLACEMENT_CHARACTER);
converterStream.writeString(string);
converterStream.close();
fileStream.close();
```

So this code does the following. If file doesn't exist it creates it and saves the data in it. However if file does exists it will return error. 
If I comment that part of the code (and file exists) it will just overwrite the old data and put the new.

I need this code to create file, if it exists just move on without an error and save the data in the new line without overwriting.

Like this.

before:

```
data11, data12, data13
data21, data22, data23
```

after:

```
data11, data12, data13
data21, data22, data23
data31, data32, data33
data41, data42, data43
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing `18` as the second parameter when you init the output stream (instead of 2).

```
fileStream.init(file, 18, 0x200, false);
```

That adds the `PR_APPEND` flag to the io mode parameter (it's `0x10`; the `2` is for `PR_WRONLY`).

Comment: Ok on the job. Will report soon how it works. OK it worked and wrote but not quite. Still I get error when I try to create already existing file and the data is not moved in the new line rather written in the same line of existing text. That could be solved with converterStream.writeString("\n"); before writing the main text. How  to solve error of creating a file?